# NSTableView reload in NSPanel (not main window)

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, reload, nspanel

From my main window i open a NSPanel in the second screen and in content view i have a NSTableView.
On reloadData the TableView make the refresh but on screen the data didn't refresh. 
I have to make F3 or change Desktop and the TableView refresh content ...
What's wrong?